# Jenkins X could not find the system vault name in namespace

Tags: jenkins-x

I am trying to add a team in `jenkins x NG` on my GKE cluster. However, the team controller is unable to setup the team and dies with the error:

```
Unable to install jx for team A: configuring the git auth: creating the git auth config service: could not find the system vault name in namespace \"NAME_OF_NAMESPACE\"
```

The default team has a properly working vault though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

team controller does not yet support GitOps management.

for now I'd install multiple teams via `jx install --namespace myotherteam --provider=gke ...`

Comment: That doesn't let me use vault for the second namespace. I'll need to create a new cluster for it to work... Or is there something I am missing?